# Is it quantum-computing or quantum-computers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are two tags: [quantum-computers](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computers) and [quantum-computing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing). Some question were moved from computing to computers.

Which tag should be the main one?

I think 'quantum computers' sounds more like hardware questions, and 'quantum computing' is a verb which is about using quantum computers for computation.

Which tag should be used then for asking AI questions? Or make another the synonym of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consolidated the tags to [quantum-computing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) because this is not an *applied* hardware and programming site.

A tag synonym isn't really appropriate here. Synonyms were intended to link two completely separate words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). For simple variations on the *same* word, there's no need to bulk up the tag listings with every word inflection. Text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> → <kbd>quantum-computing</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'd (personally) go for **computing** because it is about doing things with computers rather than the computers themselves, as you state in the question yourself.